# select top N percent of data in sheet

Tags: vba, excel

i am working on a userform where i exctract data from tables in sql server , i extract top 80 percent of data and put it in excel file with a vba code  .
what i want to do is from this 80 PERCENT of data that is alredy saved in excel sheet i want to allow the user to choose a percentage of data from the excel sheet by entering just the number in text zone  is it possible to do that ?

this is the code i am using to extract from the database from sql server :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim sSql As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmdObj As ADODB.Command
Dim qf As Object

Sheets("sheet1").Select
Selection.ClearContents

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=swat_admin;PASSWORD=swat_admin;Initial Catalog=SWAT_V2_PLL;Data Source=NCEFORREP"
sSql = "select TOP 80 PERCENT func.coresitecode,func.SiteCode,feature_id, TOTAL_PNRs,PNR_rank_id from rpt.functional_site_mapping func inner join  (select TOP 80 PERCENT * from  rpt.top_PNR_contributing_sites order by TOTAL_PNRs DESC) PNR on func.ptf_id = pnr.ptf_id and func.coresitecode = pnr.coresitecode and func.sitecode = pnr.sitecode order by PNR_rank_id  "
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.Open sSql, cn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

If rs.EOF Then
MsgBox (" the record set is empty. rs.EOF = " & rs.EOF)
Else
MsgBox ("The number of rows returned from the query is:  " & rs.RecordCount)
Range("a1").Select
For Each qf In rs.Fields
  Range("a1").Offset(0, coloffset).Value = qf.Name
  coloffset = coloffset + 1
Next qf

Range("a2").CopyFromRecordset rs
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

End If
End sub
```

here is my excel file if anyone could help me thank you  :

http://www.cjoint.com/c/FDzjyTNB1Lv

Comment: Post the code and description about the problem you're facing not the whole file.

Comment: i have edited the poste , the code is to the extraction from the DB but what  i need is to from that percentage of 80 percent i need to get N percent that N is choosed by the user from the userform in a textzone its like a filter from another filter but how to relate the text zone with the vba macro is my problem

Comment: Could you please elaborate on `[...] i want to allow the user to choose a percentage of data from the excel sheet by entering just the number in text zone [...]`? I don't quite understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: in my file i am using a userform with 3 page the first page is to extract data from the DB in sql server the code above is what i use the i want to filtre this data again to get another percentage but in this time yhe user is the one that will chose this percentage like 30% or 40% . i puted a text zone like an input so the user could type in the percentage he wants

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you get the percentage in a vb variable, say `myPercent`, 
* then check it is a number between 0 and 100
* then use it in your existing query

so

```
sSql = "select TOP 80 PERCENT
```

becomes

```
sSql = "select TOP " & myPercent & "PERCENT
```

Hope it helps

Comment: hello in fact i want to do it in inputbox is tha possible ??